# How to check image resource of an imageview programmatically?

Tags: java, android, drawable

I want to check background of my imageview and do sth if it equals to some drawable in my drawable folder. How can I do that? I have try this code but no answer:

```
layoutRoot.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view.getBackground() == R.drawable.grid_single_bg_selected) {
            //Do sth
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: getBackground() returns a Drawable so the above the code won't definitely work. How are you setting the background of the imageView ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you set the background drawable also do set a tag to the imageview

```
imageView.setTag(R.drawable.demo);
```

And then compare

```
if (((Integer) imageView.getTag()) == R.drawable.demo){
   // Do stg
}
```

Comment: I want to use this trick on grid view items. I want to access each view background and compare it. If there is a way to get id of a drawable it may  solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are setting the imageView programmatically, while setting, also set a tag to this imageView. Now, when you want to find out the drawable, you can do it by retrieving the tag of this imageView.